# If no solution for x from some system of equations exists, then does that imply that x (at least within domain of that system) does itself not exist??

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic, soft-question, intuition, information-theory

Suppose you're solving an inconsistent system. Since none of the variables can have compatible combination of values, then the answer is No Solution, ⦰.  What is the correct translation relating the tuple to this answer? In the common 3- case of $x,y,z$, is it $⟨x,y,z⟩=⦰$ or instead $[x,y,z]∈\{\}$ or are the two expressions equivalent or are neither strictly correct?

Supposing instead that one or more if not all the variables do exist, for simplicity suppo4se that $x,y$ is dependent on $z$; for $z:=f(x,y)$ then would it be apt to think of $z$ as $=0±.. 0±..$, where 0 is analogous to nullset with existence (since addition-subtraction is the lowest order of operations, it should never affect the subsequent expression, unlike as possible with e.g. 1 for multiplicative identity)?

Comment: wait, I do not understand. Consider the system: 2x plus 2y plus 2z is 0, second equation 2x plus 2y plus 2z equal 2. This is impossible system. What is your f(x,y) in this case? Is it well defined?

Comment: 2x+2y+2z=[0 and 2 simultaneously] is perhaps impossible, aye. But what if that is from combining independent and dependent variables, could that possibly cause what looks like a contradiction? Or maybe taken as sets?  Would it just be z=x+y (which allows for existence of x andor y), if z is based on x & y?  @nikola

Comment: Doesn't matter if z is dependent, since 2x + 2y + 2f(x,y) = [0 and 2] is also impossible.

Comment: Consider an easier example : x =0 and x=1. This is also an impossible system. What is "dependent" and "independent" in this case? The Relationship between coefficients make up the contradiction. Such an x which satisfied both equations does not exist.